# Why would this integral of the time derivative of the magnetic field equal zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, maxwell-equations, laser-cavity

I'm reading electrodynamics physics notes that describe a 1-dimensional cavity of length $L$. The cavity is said to lie along the $z$-axis from $-L$ to $0$. There is a reflective mirror at $z = 0$, represented by an increase in the dielectric permittivity $\epsilon(z) = \epsilon_0[1 + \Lambda \delta(z)]$, where $\Lambda$ is a parameter that determines the reflectivity of the window.

To find how the reflective mirror affects the electromagnetic field, the notes integrate Maxwell's equations across the mirror (where there is an increase in the dielectric permittivity). The notes state that, from

$$\dfrac{\partial{E}(z, t)}{\partial{z}} = - \mu_0 \dot{H}(z, t),$$

we get that

$$E(0^+, t) = E(0^-, t)$$

Doing my own calculation of this, if I'm not mistaken, we get that

$$\int^{0^+}_{0^-} \dfrac{\partial{E}(z, t)}{\partial{z}} \ dz = -\mu_0 \int^{0^+}_{0^-} \dot{H}(z, t) \ dz$$

Looking at what the author has written, it seems to me that we should then get

$$\int^{0^+}_{0^-} \dot{H}(z, t) \ dz = 0,$$

so that

$$\int^{0^+}_{0^-} \dfrac{\partial{E}(z, t)}{\partial{z}} \ dz = E(0^+, t) - E(0^-, t) = 0 \\ \Rightarrow E(0^+, t) = E(0^-, t)$$

But I don't understand why

$$\int^{0^+}_{0^-} \dot{H}(z, t) \ dz = 0$$

Why would this integral of the time derivative of the magnetic field equal zero? Or have I made an error / am I misunderstanding something?

---

Related: [Why would this integral of the time derivative of the electric field equal zero?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/687668/141502)

---

### EDIT

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that this is essentially the boundary condition for the electric field.

Comment: @CyrusTirband Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Take the time derivative outside of the integral. If $H$ is finite, the integral must be zero. This derivation is a 1D version of the typical boundary condition for the tangential electric field at an interface.

Comment: @CyrusTirband I'm unfamiliar with what you're saying. Would you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @CyrusTirband Oh, I think I understand what you're saying now. Because this is a 1-D model of a cavity, that means the integral of the fields must be zero, since there is no area?

Comment: As the other commenter already said, it's actually pretty simple. The range of integration is going to zero, so as long as your magnetic field isn't blowing up, its integral should go to zero.

Comment: @ThePointer I only mentioned the 1D part to draw the analogy with the often used electric field boundary condition for an interface, which uses the same reasoning. knzhou's comment is what I mean, although it's hard to prove that the magnetic field is finite at $z = 0$ (at least I can't).

Comment: @CyrusTirband Well, since this is modelling a physical system, we can't have an infinite magnetic field, so therefore it must be finite, right?

Comment: @ThePointer I think that would be enough for most physicists. It does feel a bit hand-wavy, as there are physical systems with points where there are singularities in the field. Although these points usually (always?) contain sources.

Comment: @CyrusTirband Thinking about this, in the context of a laser cavity, I don't think the mirrors on the ends are "sources"; it seems to me that the "source" for the magnetic/electric fields would be the gain medium, no? https://www.researchgate.net/profile/H-Rabbani-Haghighi/publication/278637278/figure/fig8/AS:670513944870916@1536874390128/Laser-cavity-composed-of-a-gain-medium-in-between-the-two-wavelength-coated.jpg

Comment: By "sources" I mean charge and current densities. I agree that the ends of the mirrors aren't sources. For all intents and purposes you can assume the magnetic field at z=0 is finite, but I personally can't think of a proof for it.

Comment: @CyrusTirband Ok, thanks for taking the time to post these comments – they've been very helpful.